# flutter_bloc is not resetting its Cubit Model values when we try to push the same screen more than one time

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

Here is my main.dart code,

```
void main() {
//  Bloc.observer = AppBlocObserver();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider<SignInCubit>(
          create: (BuildContext context) => SignInCubit(),
        ),
        BlocProvider<SignUpCubit>(
          create: (BuildContext context) => SignUpCubit(),
        ),
      ],
child: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
        return OrientationBuilder(
            builder: (BuildContext context, Orientation orientation) {
              
          //sizeConfiguration
          SizeConfig().init(constraints, orientation);
          return MaterialApp(
            title: 'Flutter Demo',
            theme: lightThemeData(context),
            darkTheme: darkThemeData(context),
            // themeMode: _themeMode,
            scaffoldMessengerKey: Messenger.rootScaffoldMessengerKey,
            navigatorKey: CustomRoutes.navigatorKey,
            home: const SplashPage(),
           initialRoute: SplashPage.id,
            routes: <String, WidgetBuilder> {
              SplashPage.id:(BuildContext context) => const SplashPage(),
              SignInPage.id: (BuildContext context) => const SignInPage(),
              SignUpPage.id: (BuildContext context) => const SignUpPage(),
            },
          );
        });
      }),
     );
  }
```

Here is the code on SignIn screen,

```
class SignInPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignInPage({super.key});

  static const String id = 'SignInPage';

  @override
  State<SignInPage> createState() => _SignInPageState();
}

class _SignInPageState extends State<SignInPage> {
  final dynamic _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();

 @override
  void initState() {
    createFocusNodeListeners();
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((Duration timeStamp) {
      _passwordFocus.addListener(_passwordListener);
    });
    super.initState();
  }

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final CTTheme cTTheme = Theme.of(context).extension<CTTheme>()!;
    //https://medium.com/codex/flutter-bloc-an-introduction-with-cubit-7eae1e740fd0
    final SignInCubitModel state = context.watch<SignInCubit>().state;
    return Scaffold(
        body: CustomPaint(
      painter:
          LoginCustomPaint(customPaintColor: cTTheme.customPaintCircleColor1),
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
        },
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const  EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24), // common padding
            child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 98,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    AppStrings.welcomeTo, // heading 3
                    style: cTTheme.heading3,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 16,
                  ),
                  RichText(
                    text: TextSpan(
                      text: AppStrings.m,
                      style: cTTheme.heading1, // heading1 with pink color
                      children: <TextSpan>[
                        TextSpan(
                          text: AppStrings.onteFiore,
                          style: cTTheme.heading2, //heading2 with pink color
                        ),
                        TextSpan(
                            text: '\n${AppStrings.c}', style: cTTheme.heading1),
                        TextSpan(
                            text: AppStrings.linical, style: cTTheme.heading2),
                        TextSpan(
                            text: ' ${AppStrings.t}', style: cTTheme.heading1),
                        TextSpan(
                            text: AppStrings.rials, style: cTTheme.heading2),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 16,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    AppStrings.findOutClinicalTrailAndStudies,
                    style: cTTheme.subtitle3, // subtitle 1
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: SizeConfig.heightMultiplier! * 19.8,
                  ),

               
                  TextFormField(
                    autofocus: false,
                    style:cTTheme.menuItemTextStyle,
                    controller: _passwordController,
                    autovalidateMode: state.passwordValidation
                        ? AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction
                        : AutovalidateMode.disabled,
                    obscureText: !state.signInPasswordVisibility,
                //   obscuringCharacter: '*',
                    focusNode: _passwordFocus,
                    decoration: kTextFieldDecoration2(context).copyWith(
                      labelText: AppStrings.password,
                       enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: state.isInvalidPassWord
                                  ? state.passWordTextFormFieldColor
                                  : cTTheme.dividerColor!)),
                      prefixIcon: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(end: 16.0),
                        child: Image.asset(// constants
                            AppIconsPath.padLockIcon),
                      ),

                      suffixIcon: InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          context
                              .read<SignInCubit>()
                              .changeSignINPassowrdVisibilty(
                                  state.signInPasswordVisibility
                                      ? ChangePasswordVisibilityEnum.invisible
                                      : ChangePasswordVisibilityEnum.visible);
                        },
                        child: state.signInPasswordVisibility
                            ? Image.asset(AppIconsPath.eyeIcon)
                            : Image.asset(AppIconsPath.privacyIcon),
                      ),
                    ),
                    onTap: () => context
                        .read<SignInCubit>()
                        .changePasswordTextFormFieldColor(
                            color: cTTheme.dividerColor!,
                            isInvalidPassWord: false),
                    onChanged: (String? value) {
                      _debouncer.run(() {
                        checkControllerValues();
                      });
                    },
                    onEditingComplete: () {
                      if (Validators.validateSignInPassword(
                              _passwordController.text) !=
                          null) {
                        context
                            .read<SignInCubit>()
                            .enableValidatorForPasswordTextField();
                      }
                    },
                    validator: (String? value) =>
                        Validators.validateSignInPassword(value!),
                  ),
                  errorMessage(state.isInvalidPassWord, 'Password Is Incorrect'),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 14,
                  ),
                  Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                      child: InkWell(
                          onTap: () async {
                            final bool isConnocted = await checkConnectivity();
                            if (isConnocted) {
                              CustomRoutes.push(
                                  screen: const ForgotPasswordPage());
                              return;
                            }

                            CustomRoutes.push(
                              screen: InternetErrorScreen(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  ConnectivityManager.internetChecker()
                                      .then((bool retry) {
                                    if (retry) {
                                      CustomRoutes.back();
                                    }
                                  });
                                },
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                          child: Text(
                            AppStrings.forgotPassword,
                            style: cTTheme.description1,
                          ))),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 48,
                  ),
                  PrimaryButton(
                    onPressed: state.isSignInButtonDissabled
                        ? null
                        : () {
                           FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
                            if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                            context.read<SignInCubit>().onSignInSubmit(
                                _emailOrPhoneController.text,
                                _passwordController.text);
                             }
                          },
                    text: AppStrings.signIn.toUpperCase(),
                    isLoadingVisible: state.isLoading,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 16,
                  ),
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () async {
                      final bool isConnocted = await checkConnectivity();
                      if (isConnocted) {
                        Navigator.pushNamed(context, SignUpPage.id);
                       // CustomRoutes.pushreplace(screen: const SignUpPage());
                        return;
                      }

                      CustomRoutes.push(
                          screen: InternetErrorScreen(onPressed: () {
                        ConnectivityManager.internetChecker()
                            .then((bool retry) {
                          if (retry) {
                            CustomRoutes.back();
                          }
                        });
                      }));
                    },
                    child: Center(
                      child: RichText(
                        text: TextSpan(
                          text: AppStrings.dontHaveAnAccount,
                          style: cTTheme.subtitle2,
                          children: <TextSpan>[
                            TextSpan(
                                text: ' ${AppStrings.signUp}',
                                style: cTTheme.iconButtonTextStyle),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                 const SizedBox(
                    height: 66,
                  ),
                  Center(
                      child: Text(
                    AppStrings.byLoggingInYouAgreeToOur,
                    style: cTTheme.noteTextStyle1,
                  )),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 6,
                  ),
                  Center(
                      child: InkWell(
                    onTap: () => CustomRoutes.push(
                        screen: InternetErrorScreen(onPressed: () {
                      ConnectivityManager.internetChecker().then((bool value) {
                        if (value) {
                          CustomRoutes.back();
                        }
                      });
                    })),
                    child: Text(
                      AppStrings.termsAndpolicies,
                      style: cTTheme.noteTextStyle2,
                    ),
                  )),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
```

I am switching(show/hide) eye icon on the password textfield to show and hide the eye image using "changeSignINPassowrdVisibilty" function from cubit file. Here is the Cubit file code,

```
class SignInCubit extends Cubit<SignInCubitModel> {
  SignInCubit()
      : super(
            SignInCubitModel()); // here inside SignInCubit class,  all the fields are already initialized
  final CTTheme cTTheme =
      Theme.of(CustomRoutes.navigatorKey.currentContext!).extension<CTTheme>()!;
  void changeSignINPassowrdVisibilty(ChangePasswordVisibilityEnum newState) {
    emit(state.copyWith(
        signInPasswordVisibility:
            newState == ChangePasswordVisibilityEnum.visible));
  }
}
```

Here is the code from SignInCubitModel class,

```
class SignInCubitModel {
  SignInCubitModel({
    this.signInPasswordVisibility = false,
    
  });
  bool signInPasswordVisibility;
 

  SignInCubitModel copyWith({
    bool? signInPasswordVisibility,
   
  }) {
    return SignInCubitModel(
      signInPasswordVisibility:
          signInPasswordVisibility ?? this.signInPasswordVisibility,
    );
  }
}
```

Initially signInPasswordVisibility field value is false. When user try to switch visibility of the password , signInPasswordVisibility will change its value to true or false.

Here is my problem,

1.I am enabling signInPasswordVisibility to true on SignIn screen by clicking eye icon. Please note now signInPasswordVisibility value is true.

And

2.I am pushing to Signup screen when they click signup button from SignIn screen.

And

3.I am pushing to SignIn screen again when they click SignIn button from signup screen.

But this time signInPasswordVisibility value in SignIn screen still remains true. Its supposed to be false since I am pushing to this screen again. It has to reset the all SignIn screen state values when I push to SignIn screen. But Its not happening.

Signin screen still keeps old state values even if I push to the Signin screen multiple time.

Is there any problem with the way I implemented flutter_bloc? OR Is there any solution to reset the state values every time we push the SignIn screen?